# Autoloader function tries to include a built-in PHP class

Tags: php, class, autoloader

I have created a class for database manipulation. 
This class inherits from the PDO class.
When using that class an error appears `Fatal error: Class 'app\lib\PDO' not found`.
Note that I have used the backslash `\` with the inheritance from PDO.

```
class Database extends \PDO {

    private static $object;
    private static $pdo;

    function __construct() {
        $db_config = Config::getItem('database');
        try {
            $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $db_config['db_host'] . ";dbname=" . $db_config['db_name'] . ";charset=" . $db_config['db_charset'] . "";
            parent::__construct($dsn, $db_config['db_username'], $db_config['db_password']);
        } catch (\PDOException $err) {
            trigger_error($err->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
......
```

Comment: instead put `use \PDO` in top of your file

Comment: @Nytrix maybe he used PDO in another place in its file.

Comment: Yes, actually @MoeinPorkamel is right. It's not the `extends \PDO`, that one is fine. As you are still in the namespace `app\lib` when you are loading `PDO`. As you can see in the error. That class does not exist in that namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tried loading `PDO` in the *wrong* namespace. It's not in the code we are presented though. As you can see in the error `Fatal error: Class 'app\lib\PDO' not found`, it tries to load the `PDO` class in the namespace `app\lib`. As you probably know, it's not in that namespace.

In order to fix that, you can put this on top of your file:

```
use \PDO;
```

Or you need to put the `\` before every usage of the `PDO` class. To learn more about namespacing, check out the [**documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

`PDO` is a *"normal"* class, it has a namespace declaration, if you do not load it within that namespace, it won't be found. Just like any other class. In your case, again, you have it in the `app\lib` namespace. So, you'll have to use the `PDO` class within the `\PDO` namespace, as that is what namespace that class is in.

Comment: Thanks, `use \PDO` works fine. but I know you use that statement with your classes, not with the built-in classes.

Comment: @LionKing That is because you are in the namespace of `app\lib` and the `PDO` class is **not** in that namespace. I hope that makes sense. It's in the base `\ ` namespace, instead of `app\lib`. That is why you do the whole  `use \PDO` thing. To add to that, `PDO` is nothing more then a class.

Comment: I think because I am in `app\lib` namespace I used `\PDO` when inherits from PDO, so what is the benefit of using backslash, this for global namespace.

Comment: You use `PDO` somewhere without the namespace addition, thus the error. In the code you showed us, it seems all fine, at least for the namespace matter. Somewhere else, you used to wrong namespace for the `PDO` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by checking if file exists, here is a generic code that you can use in all autoload cases, and no need for the " \ "

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
  if(file_exists(SITE_PATH . 'app/classes/'. $class .'.php')){
    require_once SITE_PATH . 'app/classes/'. $class .'.php';
  }elseif(file_exists(SITE_PATH . 'app/another-folder/'. $class .'.php')){
    require_once SITE_PATH . 'app/another-folder/'. $class .'.php';
  }
});
```

Comment: No, that is not the issue. It's not a loading issue, it's a namspace issue.

Comment: @Nytrix I guess the question title is misleading